# system app not working

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, system

I have a widget to turn data connection on and off. Since I upgraded my Nexus 4 to Lollipop, I get the message `"widgetsoid needs to be installed as a system app"`

So I rooted the phone, moved the apk file from `/data/app` to `/system/app`. I set the permission to 644. Rebooted the phone.
Still, I get the the same error message. Do I have to uninstall the app, and reinstall it from the apk?

**What am I doing wrong?** I use a custom launcher, if that matters.

Comment: Can you post the complete name of widgetsoid apk folder that you moved?

Answer (score 1):

How to install Widgetsoid in `system/app` folder?

With ADB connected to the phone:

1. Mount`/system` in read-write mode.
2. Run the command `adb push Widgetsoid.apk /system/app/Widgetsoid.apk`
3. Remount `/system` as read-only.
4. Reboot your phone.